# Olx-like database design

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Friends i am working on a web project that is a free classified ad site. Its just like http://www.olx.com. I am not getting the idea of how http://www.olx.com.database is designed. can anyone help me in this regard. i just need the "big picture" not minor details. Means how they have structured their database in relation to their product/service categories and how data passes to database etc.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 20):

you can take reference from the below schema used in open source classified engine [osclass](http://osclass.org)

source:http://doc.osclass.org/Database_model_and_diagram
[image: database schema for a classified website]